# ActiveAdmin calculations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to implement some calculation to my admin interface, so i have a **product** resource, at this resource you see a list of services that I do, such as airbrushing, price on application considered as, for example (**1 $ per 1 square cm**).

How i can better realize this idea?

I would like to see when a user pushing a button **"New Product"** it was a field where he writes the number of square centimeters and on the basis of these dimensions, it automatically render the required amount in the currency.

---

**Rails 4.1.0**

**ActiveAdmin 1.0.0**

**ruby 2.1**

---

Just now you can only type a fixed price, like fixed price for 1 product/service.

**app/admin/product.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product, { :sort_order => :name_asc } do

    # Scopes
    scope :all, :default => true
    scope :available do |products|
        products.where("available < ?", Date.today)
    end
    scope :drafts do |products|
        products.where("available > ?", Date.today)
    end
    scope :featured_products do |products|
        products.where(:featured => true)
    end

    # Permitted parameters
    permit_params :article_id, :title, :description, :price, :featured, :available, :image_file_name

    # Displayed columns
    index do
    selectable_column
        column :article,  :sortable => :article
        column :title,    :sortable => :title
        column :description
    # Currency helper
        column :price, :sortable => :price do |cur|
            number_to_currency cur.price, locale: :ru
        end
        column :featured
        column :available
    #   column :image_file_name
        actions
    end

    # Product details
    show do
        panel "Product Details" do
            attributes_table_for product do
                row("Article")           { link_to product.article }
                row("Title")             { product.title }
                row("Description")       { product.description }
                row("Price")             { product.price }
                row("Featured")          { product.featured }
                row("Available on")      { product.available }
                row("Image")             { image_tag("products/" + product.image_file_name) }
            end
        end
    end
    # Filters
    filter :article,      :as => :select
    filter :title,        :as => :select               # :check_boxes (for checkboxes)
    filter :price,        :as => :select
    filter :available,    :as => :select
    filter :featured,     :as => :check_boxes
end
```

**app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationship
    belongs_to :article

    # Named Scopes
    scope :available, lambda{ where("available < ?", Date.today) }
    scope :drafts,    lambda{ where("available > ?", Date.today) }

    # Validations
    validates :article, :title, :description, :price, :available, :presence => true
    validates :featured, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }
end
```

**app/models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationship
    has_many :products, :dependent => :delete_all

    # Validations
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true

    # Define for display a article for products as article code
    def to_s
        "#{title}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to show a price on the form page when the user has entered the dimension? Before saving it?